# ld: 12 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native, clang

I am running into a build error that I believe is most likely derived from Objective-C/Swift + React Native Adapter/Linker.

After the last time I successfully submitted a new build to App Store Connect, I immediately became incapable to successfully generating an XCode build. Nothing had changed! I literally didn't touch the code base for about 6 days, and suddenly I was generating broken builds. I have always used XCode to generate my builds, while I test & develop my app on my physical iPhone device.

My package.json:

```json
{
    "private": true,
    "main": "index.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": "14.17.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-native start",
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "mac": "npx react-native run-macos",
        "react-devtools": "react-devtools",
        "flow": "flow"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^3.7.0",
        "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.1.2",
        "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
        "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.0",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
        "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.8.0",
        "@react-native-community/slider": "3.0.3",
        "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.16.1",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.10.2",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "components": "file:./components",
        "expo-av": "^9.2.3",
        "expo-constants": "^11.0.1",
        "expo-contacts": "^9.2.5",
        "expo-crypto": "^9.2.0",
        "expo-device": "^3.3.0",
        "expo-facebook": "^11.3.1",
        "expo-file-system": "^11.1.3",
        "expo-google-app-auth": "^8.1.3",
        "expo-in-app-purchases": "^10.2.0",
        "expo-linking": "^2.3.1",
        "expo-location": "^12.1.2",
        "expo-secure-store": "^10.2.0",
        "expo-sms": "^9.2.3",
        "expo-splash-screen": "^0.11.2",
        "firebase": "^8.6.8",
        "form-data": "^4.0.0",
        "node-apple-receipt-verify": "^1.10.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-native": "0.64.2",
        "react-native-appearance": "~0.3.3",
        "react-native-config": "^1.4.2",
        "react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^2.5.1",
        "react-native-error-boundary": "^1.1.10",
        "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.6",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
        "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.36.2",
        "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.0",
        "react-native-modalize": "^2.0.8",
        "react-native-pager-view": "^5.1.9",
        "react-native-push-notification": "^7.4.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
        "react-native-restart": "0.0.22",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0",
        "react-native-sectionlist-contacts": "^1.1.3",
        "react-native-sortable-list": "0.0.24",
        "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.5.0",
        "react-native-unimodules": "^0.14.3",
        "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
        "react-native-view-overflow": "0.0.5",
        "react-native-webview": "^11.6.1",
        "unimodules-permissions-interface": "^6.1.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.13.16",
        "@babel/core": "^7.14.2",
        "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.13.13",
        "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
        "flow-bin": "^0.155.1",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1",
        "prettierrc": "0.0.0-5",
        "react-devtools": "^4.14.0",
        "react-native-codegen": "0.0.7",
        "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
        "sharp-cli": "^1.14.1"
    },
    "name": "react-native-app",
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

My XCode Build Error Log:

```
duplicate symbol '_EXCanAskAgain' in:
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a(EXPermissionsService.o)
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXPermissionsService.o)
duplicate symbol '_EXExpiresKey' in:
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a(EXPermissionsService.o)
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXPermissionsService.o)
duplicate symbol '_EXGrantedKey' in:
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a(EXPermissionsService.o)
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXPermissionsService.o)
duplicate symbol '_EXPermissionExpiresNever' in:
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a(EXPermissionsService.o)
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXPermissionsService.o)
duplicate symbol '_EXStatusKey' in:
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a(EXPermissionsService.o)
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXPermissionsService.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_EXPermissionsService' in:
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a(EXPermissionsService.o)
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXPermissionsService.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_EXPermissionsService._moduleRegistry' in:
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a(EXPermissionsService.o)
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXPermissionsService.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_EXPermissionsService._requesters' in:
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a(EXPermissionsService.o)
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXPermissionsService.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_EXPermissionsService._requestersByClass' in:
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a(EXPermissionsService.o)
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXPermissionsService.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_EXPermissionsService' in:
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a(EXPermissionsService.o)
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXPermissionsService.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy' in:
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a(EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy.o)
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy' in:
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a(EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy.o)
    /Users/davidcarrillojr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GlobeChat-gwrzspklsexqfbdkcqokomncvcbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy.o)
ld: 12 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried the following commands, in an attempt to clear my cache(s):

bash script used to clean project root dir:

```sh
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && npm cache clean --force
rm -rf debug.log
rm -rf package-lock.json && rm -rf node_modules

# Inside my `ios` dir:
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf Podfile.lock
pod cache clean --all # will clean all pods
pod deintegrate
pod setup
```

My `Podfile`:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'


platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'GlobeChat' do
  use_unimodules!
  config = use_native_modules!
    
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # :hermes_enabled => true
  )

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I post this, am I facing the same issue. I have to try it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70967340/local-environment-cause-expo-build-crash-on-testflight

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in October of 2021, Expo made some updates to their modules & those updates caused breaking changes for me since I was in an ejected expo environment. I ended up re-integrating my app into the newly release Expo 43 & re-established an Expo shell arounds my app. After doing this, and using the ExpoModules instead of react_unimodules, I was able to successfully build my app both on the simulator & on my real device.

Moral of the story, if you become very dependent on modules in a bare react-native workflow, it becomes very important to monitor the changes those module maintainers make to their modules.