# local environment cause expo build crash on Testflight

Tags: react-native, crash, expo, runtime-error

My code runs well on ios simulators and but it crashes on Testflight. When my friend clones the code and their code runs great with Testflight. It must be my environment settings then. Here is what I think might cause the issue:

1.when I do expo run: ios --configuration Release, Error: cannot find ‘ExpoModule’ in scope

2.“expo”: “^44.0.0”,
“expo-constants”: “~13.0.1”,
“react”: “17.0.1”,
“react-dom”: “17.0.1”,
“react-native”: “0.64.3”,
“yarn”: “1.22.17”,
“npm”: “6.14.14”,
"node":"12.17.5",
“expo-CLI”: " 5.0.3",

3.expo run:ios --configuration Release.  generate tar file, and it crashes on the simulator as well, the crash code said

Feb  3 00:04:19 Xs-iMac OrgCorescore[69361]: assertion failed: 20C69 18E182: libxpc.dylib + 50305 [454053CA-B690-3B99-BE31-2369B04EA493]: 0x7d
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.DACCEDA2-9E0B-4CA7-AF56-C134FBF4F4C9[49383] (UIKitApplication:org.core[0d61][rb-legacy][69361]): Service exited due to SIGABRT
Feb  3 00:04:19 XIs-iMac OrgCorescore[69362]: assertion failed: 20C69 18E182: libxpc.dylib + 50305 [454053CA-B690-3B99-BE31-2369B04EA493]: 0x7d

Thank you so much.